# How to launch a local Kubernetes With Vagrant

Tags: python, kubernetes, namespaces, vagrant, kubeadm

As a developer, I want to launch a local Kubernetes development environment automatically using kubeadm. I expect to create my environment running "vagrant up", and after that I must be able to login into the Vagrant VM and run kubectl commands.

I want to include a simple Python script that list all the running pods in all the namespaces. Call this script at the end of "vagrant up or provision" process to validate Kubernetes installation.

Finally I want to upload the scripts to GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

What i have is a *bootstrap* script called from my *Vagrantfile*, for example:

```
config.vm.provision :shell, path:./bootstrap.sh, privileged: false, :args => arguments_for_bootstrap
```

In such bootstrap script i install the software necessary to run my kubernetes stuff. As this is a vagrant machine, i would suggest standalone *minikube* "cluster". If using docker technology for containers, i would install, for example *docker*, *kubectl* and *minikube*, and probably, some more things like *helm* orchestrator, etc.

For example:

```
### DOCKER ###
sudo apt-get update
# Install packages to allow apt to use a repository over HTTPS
sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common
# Add Dockers official GPG key
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
# Set up the stable repository
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
# Update
sudo apt-get update
# Install docker-ce
sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce=18.06.3~ce~3-0~ubuntu
# Add user to group 'docker'
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER

### KUBECTL ###
curl -Lo kubectl https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.14.8/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl && chmod +x kubectl && sudo mv kubectl /usr/local/bin/

### MINIKUBE ###
curl -Lo minikube https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/v1.4.0/minikube-linux-amd64 && chmod +x minikube && sudo mv minikube /usr/local/bin/
# Start
sudo minikube start --vm-driver=none
# Configure permissions
[ -d /root/.kube ] && sudo mv /root/.kube $HOME/.kube # this will write over any previous configuration
sudo chown -R $USER $HOME/.kube
sudo chgrp -R $USER $HOME/.kube
[ -d /root/.minikube ] && sudo mv /root/.minikube $HOME/.minikube # this will write over any previous configuration
sudo chown -R $USER $HOME/.minikube
sudo chgrp -R $USER $HOME/.minikube
```

Finally, i would add provision scripts to do whatever checking you need. If you prefer python script, you could use kubectl api for python (i.e. https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python), but i suggest directly bash scripting:

```
kubectl get pod --all-namespaces
```

The best way to afford tasks on provision, is using *scriptlets* which you can enable/disable just by giving +x permission:

```
    @files = Dir.glob(provision.d + "/*").sort
    @files.each do |file|
      next if file == '.' or file == '..'
      next if not File.stat(file).executable?
      config.vm.provision :shell, path:file, privileged: false
    end
```

Then, you would have locally a bunch of scriptlets to do things in specific order:

```
provision.d/K01_helm_install_my_app
...
provision.d/K30_check_k8s_health
```

Regarding your third question, i assume that having a *github* account, all the scripts necessary to recreate your development environment would be your *Vagrantfile*, bootstrap.sh script, and provision.d directory with *scriptlets* inside to do all the steps you consider to do on *vagrant up*.